# Get view projections from information_schema

Tags: sql, postgresql, information-schema

I have a simple view as following:

```
CREATE VIEW AS
(
    SELECT identifier AS id FROM persons
);
```

Does the `information_schema` views provide functionality to find out that column `identifier` from table `persons` is projected as column `id` in the view?

The view `information_schema.view_column_usage` only shows that column `identifier` from `persons` is used, but not that it is projected into `id` in the view.

Is there something else I could use from `information_schema`?

Comment: I don't think that information is stored anywhere.

Comment: You can get the definition of the view with `SELECT definition FROM pg_catalog.pg_views;`. But it's just the `SELECT` behind it. You'd have to parse that yourself, to get the information you want, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not stored anywhere in `information_schema`.

Of course it has to be stored *somewhere*, but that is in the `ev_action` column of the `pg_rewrite` system catalog, in the row for the `_RETURN` rule of the view.

That column has the internal data type `pg_node_tree` that stores the parsed form of a query, so there is no way to analyze it from SQL.